# How to center scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

how is it possible to center a div's scrollbar?

This is what I have:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="width:1000px;overflow:auto;">
   <img src="..." style="width:100%;height:250px;" />
</div>

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    $('#mydiv').scrollLeft(
            $( "#mydiv" ).width() - $( "#mydiv" ).width()/2
    );
});
```

But this doesn't work. It is not exactly centering. Too bad I can't set percent 50%. The scrollLeft(() function requires an integer.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/HSJft/

Comment: @JasonP, yes, but when the #mydiv is resized (for example when you resize your browser), the scrollbar isn't centered any more. Check this for example: http://jsfiddle.net/HSJft/1/

Comment: I tried it, and it seems to work.
http://jsfiddle.net/vJrEN/

@UDB is right I changed the with of your image too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is your solution i have checked it with every possible width which was less than the image width. Even measured both left and right side space of scroll bar with plastic ruler ..LOL. :) to check if both sides are equal

http://jsfiddle.net/HSJft/5/

```js
var outer=document.getElementById('mydiv').offsetWidth
var inner=document.getElementById('im').offsetWidth;
console.log(inner);
$('#mydiv').scrollLeft((inner-outer)/2)
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" style="overflow:auto; overflow-y:hidden;width:300px">
   <img id="im" src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-15.jpg" />
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but inside the #mydiv there is an image map (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp). Do i have to change all of them to width:inherit?

Comment: @Jordy m sorry but i can't tell without seeing a working example can you please edit your question and provide full code or make a fiddle of your code

Comment: Look, this isn't working: jsfiddle.net/HSJft/2 The image is displayed to exactly match the div's width and height,  but I need a scrollbar to display the image in its orginal width and height.

Comment: @Jordy do yo want both vertical and horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: Only horizontal scroll bar is ok!

Comment: @Jordy i have included the link in the answer, have a look at it,is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your help! But the horizontal scrollbar is completely to the right, I need it to be centered...

Comment: @Jordy see the image that is the result i get when the fiddle script runs, have you changed the width of your `div`?

Comment: See this image: http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/4632/v42l.png. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Jordy check the link in answer

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution: 
https://jsfiddle.net/HSJft/21/

Vertical Scroll: 
`$(scrollWrapper).scrollTop(($(content).height() - $(scrollWrapper).height())/2);`

Horizontal Scroll:  
`$(scrollWrapper).scrollLeft(($(content).width() - $(scrollWrapper).width())/2);`