# How can I force the horizontal scrollbar to center when page loads

Tags: html, css

I have a timer that sits ontop of an image. The timer represents a countdown to a specific date. The problem is when the browser is resized the timer will hold true but the banner will stretch etc. I have noticed if I set the website to width 130% it will work flawlessly. The only issue is the horizonal scrollbar upon launch will default to the left. I am trying to have it default to the center.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name= viewport content= width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>

              @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@600&display=swap');
              @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap');
              @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap');
              @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo:ital,wght@1,800&family=Oswald&display=swap');
              @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rowdies:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');
              @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Festive&display=swap');

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}      

body {
  background-color: #00628c;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.remaining-time {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--time-unit-wrapper-top);
  left: var(--time-unit-wrapper-left);
}   

.remaining-time .separator {
  padding: var(--time-unit-seperator-padding);
  color: #FFFFFF00;
  font-size: 12px;
}   

.remaining-time .days,
.remaining-time .hours,
.remaining-time .minutes,
.remaining-time .seconds {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: var(--time-unit-width);
  background-color: var(--time-unit-background-color);
  color: var(--time-unit-color);
  font-size: var(--time-unit-font-size);
  font-family: var(--time-unit-font-family);
  border-radius: 25%;
}

:root {
  --time-unit-wrapper-top: 27.5%;
  --time-unit-wrapper-left: 44%;
  --time-unit-seperator-padding: 0 8px;
  --time-unit-width: 20px;
  --time-unit-background-color: #FFFFFF00;
  --time-unit-color: #E5D5B5;
  --time-unit-border-radius: 4px;
  --time-unit-font-size: 13px;
  --time-unit-font-family: 'Exo';
}

</style>
</head>     

<body>

     <div class="hpf_body">
          <img src="/CServer/HomepageFeed/7D30D9006D4E4156BE0F54B95A6CFB69/LMSNEW.gif" alt="banner" width="500%" style="width: 100%;">  

    <div class="remaining-time">
      <span class="days"></span>
      <span class="separator">:</span>
      <span class="hours"></span>
      <span class="separator">:</span>
      <span class="minutes"></span>
      <span class="separator">:</span>
      <span class="seconds"></span>
    </div>               

        </div>       

  </header>   

  <script>
    let intervalHandler;
    // (year, months, date, hours, minutes, seconds)
    const startTime = new Date(2022, 1, 9, 10, 45, 0);
    const endTime = new Date(2022, 7, 12, 0, 0, 0);   

    const header = document.querySelector('.header');
    const remainingDaysSpan = document.querySelector('.remaining-time .days');
    const remainingHoursSpan = document.querySelector('.remaining-time .hours');
    const remainingMinutesSpan = document.querySelector('.remaining-time .minutes');
    const remainingSecondsSpan = document.querySelector('.remaining-time .seconds');     

    const addLeadingZero = str => {
      return (str.length == 1) ? '0' + str : str;
    }

    const updateRemainingTime = () => {
      const curTime = new Date();
      const timeDffSecs = (endTime - curTime) / 1000;   

      if(timeDffSecs <= 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalHandler);
        return;
      }     

      const remainingSeconds = timeDffSecs;
      const remainingMinutes = remainingSeconds / 60;
      const remainingHours = remainingMinutes / 60;
      const remainingDays = remainingHours / 24;     

      remainingDaysSpan.innerText = addLeadingZero(Math.floor(remainingDays).toString());
      remainingHoursSpan.innerText = addLeadingZero(Math.floor(remainingHours % 24).toString());
      remainingMinutesSpan.innerText = addLeadingZero(Math.floor(remainingMinutes % 60).toString());
      remainingSecondsSpan.innerText = addLeadingZero(Math.floor(remainingSeconds % 60).toString()); 
    }     

    intervalHandler = setInterval(() => {
      updateRemainingTime();
    }, 100);
  </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: won't downvote or anything simillar with this question. This is just an opinion. If you have, on any web page, horizontal scroll bar at load, You are not doing a good web.

Comment: Java does not run inside the browser, so this question is not related to Java.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593062/how-to-center-scrollbar